# Checking file owner permissions

Tags: bash, permissions

I'm trying to test if a file has the execute bit set for the owner in bash script.

I know `if [ -x filename ]` checks for execute permission for the User running the statement but i need to know if the owner has it. Is there a way to specify owner?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `stat` to get the file permissions, and parse them with another command to get the character you want.

```
stat -c %A someFile
```

Returns something like:

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

**EDIT:** Here you go:

```
stat -c %A someFile | sed 's/...\(.\).\+/\1/'
```

Returns either `-` or `x` if the owner has execute.

**EDIT 2:** For completion's sake:

```
if [ `stat -c %A someFile | sed 's/...\(.\).\+/\1/'` == "x" ] 
then
  echo "Owner has execute permission!"
fi
```

**EDIT 3:** If you prefer numerical permissions:

`stat -c %a /path/to/a/file` will output 600 or 700 or whatever 3 digit base-8 number.

Comment: if [ $(stat -c %a some-file) != 600 ]; then ... was what I wanted.

Comment: `%a` is a great format. A simpler way to retrieve the 4th character is `stat -c %A someFile | cut -c4`.

Comment: It saved my time :)